# Apply filters to video while preview and save it with applied filter and original audio in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, video-processing

I am new to video processing. I want to apply a filter to a video at runtime, and I want to save that video after filter applied.

Regarding this I'm doing a research. I has gone through many libraries but I'm struggling to achieve my aim.

### Developement environment

```
Migw-64 with windows 7 64 bit
Android Studio 2.1 preview 5
heap space 4GB 
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0
android-ndk-r12-win-x86_64
com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0  --> to build NDK
```

### I have tried

1. **AndroidFastImageprocessingLibrary**

   Chrisbatt -> [AndroidFastImageProcessing in github](https://github.com/chrisbatt/AndroidFastImageProcessing)

   This library use GLSurfaceview to display filters but we could not save it to mp4 file.

   So I found another implementation of it [icmobilelab](https://github.com/icmobilelab/AndroidFastImageProcessing/blob/master/framework/FastImageProcessing/src/project/android/imageprocessing/output/VideoFileEndpoint.java) -> AndroidFastImageProcessing in github

   This library use JavaCV with ffmpeg compiled. But it failed.
2. **JavaCV**

   JavaCV use outdated ffmpeg and it is abandoned.
3. **Grafika** -> [on github](https://github.com/google/grafika)

   I tried Android Fast Image Processing with RecordFBOActivity in grafika. But i have failed. This library use MediaRecorder to record the  contents of GLSurfaceView. But it records video without audio (I have tested the RecordFBOActivity and analyze the code).
4. **filter packs in platform_frameworks**

   [github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/mca/filterpacks/java/android/filterpacks/videosink/MediaEncoderFilter.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/mca/filterpacks/java/android/filterpacks/videosink/MediaEncoderFilter.java)
   its android 4.2 edited core. I can't run this code because too many jni dependencies.
5. **ffmpeg**

   [github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg)
   I tried ffmpeg3.1 compilation procedure implemented by guardianproject. it successfullay built a static library but i cannot build dynamic library (so files). I'm stuck with a linker error. I think the linking order matters. I tried the linking order specified in below link
   https://fritzone.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/link-with-static-ffmpeg/
   but it won't help. the following error occurs

   ```
   [armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libffmpeg.so
   jni/ffmpeg.c:200: error: undefined reference to 'av_frame_alloc'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:201: error: undefined reference to 'av_frame_alloc'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:209: error: undefined reference to 'av_register_all'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:210: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_register_all'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:45: error: undefined reference to 'avformat_open_input'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:50: error: undefined reference to 'avformat_find_stream_info'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:56: error: undefined reference to 'av_find_best_stream'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:63: error: undefined reference to 'av_opt_set_int'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:66: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_open2'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:67: error: undefined reference to 'av_log'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:78: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_get_by_name'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:79: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_get_by_name'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:80: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_inout_alloc'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:81: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_inout_alloc'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:85: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_graph_alloc'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:98: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_graph_create_filter'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:106: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_graph_create_filter'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:113: error: undefined reference to 'av_int_list_length_for_size'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:113: error: undefined reference to 'av_opt_set_bin'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:116: error: undefined reference to 'av_log'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:131: error: undefined reference to 'av_strdup'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:142: error: undefined reference to 'av_strdup'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:147: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_graph_parse_ptr'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:151: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_graph_config'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:155: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_inout_free'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:156: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_inout_free'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:218: error: undefined reference to 'av_read_frame'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:223: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_decode_video2'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:230: error: undefined reference to 'av_frame_get_best_effort_timestamp'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:233: error: undefined reference to 'av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:234: error: undefined reference to 'av_log'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:240: error: undefined reference to 'av_buffersink_get_frame'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:171: error: undefined reference to 'av_rescale_q'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:246: error: undefined reference to 'av_frame_unref'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:248: error: undefined reference to 'av_frame_unref'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:251: error: undefined reference to 'av_packet_unref'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:254: error: undefined reference to 'avfilter_graph_free'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:255: error: undefined reference to 'avcodec_close'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:256: error: undefined reference to 'avformat_close_input'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:257: error: undefined reference to 'av_frame_free'
   jni/ffmpeg.c:258: error: undefined reference to 'av_frame_free'
   jni/include/libavutil/error.h:111: error: undefined reference to 'av_strerror'
   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libffmpeg.so] Error 1
   ```
6. **MediaCodec, MediaExtractor,MediaRecord,MediaMuxer**

   Finally I planned to combine AndroidFastImageProcessing with MediaCodec, MediaExtractor,MediaRecord,MediaMuxer.

   So I try to Extract audio from video using mediamuxer
   https://gist.github.com/sayan801/9a39ccad0818d2b3499a.
   I use mp4 video (MIME Type video/avc  that have 2 tracks audio and video) to extract audio but the resultant file is corrupted (just 4 kb)

I think this question is another view of the existing problem if anybody experienced this problem please guide me.

Comment: I use https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus which has ffmpeg compiled in; you can optionally add opencv and some crazy face detection library, but I compile it out (it over doubles the size of output).